# how to get data table to json array in c#

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0

how i can get a json array return from data table in asmx service menthods.

am coded like this but am not getting in array

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration = 500)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json,  XmlSerializeString = false)]
 public  String latency(int testId)
        {

          SqlConnection   conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
          SqlDataAdapter  da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetValues", conn);
          da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TestId", testId));
          DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            string[][] JaggedArray = new string[dt.Rows.Count][];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow rs in dt.Rows)
            {
               JaggedArray[i] = new string[] { rs["Time"].ToString(), rs["minlatency"].ToString() };
                i = i + 1;
            }
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JaggedArray);

            return json;

        }
```

my response is

{"d":"[[\"2/3/2012 11:30:14 AM\",\"10\"],[\"2/3/2012 11:30:16 AM\",\"5\"],[\"2/3/2012 11:30:18 AM\",\"7\"]]"}

Answer (score 0):

You may try .NET Framework's [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) :

```
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var serialized = serializer.Serialize(
            new int[][]
                {
                    new []{1,2,3},
                    new []{4,5,6}
                }
            );
        Console.WriteLine(serialized);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

## NOTE:

JavaScriptSerializer has been reported to be **slower** than Json.NET.